# Windows 8.1 cannot download apps 0x0x80246013 error

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I am on Windows 8.1 Enterprise and am having a hard time trying to download and run apps on my PC. If I try to run, say the Mail app, I get the message "This app can't open. Go to store". There it asks to repair, but it really doesn't do anything. It says that it was installed, but get the same error.

I notice on the top right in the Store that it says that 14 apps couldn't be updated. When i try to update I get the 0x0x80246013 error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6f119828-dd1b-42da-b8b5-c6e6c0d5617c/no-apps-or-windows-store-work-after-upgrading-to-windows-81-enterprise?forum=w8itproinstall) and it finally worked.

1. Open registry editor typing regedit.exe from a command line.

   1. Browse to the registry key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\appmodel\repository\packages.
   2. Right click on the “packages” key and bring up the “Permissions” tab.
   3. Click the “Advanced” button located at the bottom right corner.
   4. Check to see the account name that shows up as the “Owner” (this is the first line of text on the “advanced security settings” dialog for the “packages” key). It should say “SYSTEM”.  (For me this showed the built-in local Administrators group)
   5. If it is any other account, click on the “Change” button next to it.
   6. Type SYSTEM in the “select user” dialog. If “Multiple Names Found” window comes up, select the row for “SYSTEM”.
   7. Click OK to the dialogs and close them all.
   8. Run from admin command prompt:     Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml

2) Fixing all modern apps:
Run from admin PowerShell:
((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications") | Get-ItemProperty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode

```
* When I ran this the black X persisted until after the next step and reboot.  But trying to start an app gives me a new message and a link to the store.
```

3) Fixing 3rd party apps:
Delete the regkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore[UserSid]

4) Restart.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need windows 8.1 update 1 installed to get updates.  I would also check and make sure your time is right